# jquery-ui dialog do not open

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

the html code for this dialog:

```
      <div id="dialog" title="Erro" style="display: none;">
        <div id="content"></div>
      </div>
```

the jquery code:

```
$( function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    maxHeight: 640,
    minWidth: 480
  });
  $("#btn_dialog").on("click", function(event){
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog("open");
  });
});
```

when I try open the dialog, i get this error in the browser (chrome) console:

```
$(...).dialog is not a function
```

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Try to declare your scripts at the end of your code. (before the body closing tags), Solved many similar problems for me personally.

Comment: jquery-ui is not properly import on your page.

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle yes, this what i did. all the scripts are in the end of the page.

Comment: Are you by any chance putting this inside a user control in asp.net? I have had some funny behavior from Jquery UI before in that case.

Comment: @JaxTeller yes, it is. in fact, when I remove the options, the dialog is opened without problems

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle no, i not even using asp.net (java/spring project)

Comment: Can you put your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: I just copy/paste your code on this https://jsfiddle.net/wqtc04uy/ all work fine... I think you have script conflicts or something

Comment: Do you see this error or any other errors in your console? On other browsers? What version of jQuery are you loading? jQuery UI? Please provide a better example of your code using jsfiddle or plunker.